# Remove multiple images in source code that are back to back except the last one

Tags: php, mysql, html-parsing

OK, here is what I want to do. I have a MySql database that has articles in it. Some of the artictles have
images in them, and some have multiple images back to back in them like this...

```
    $preoutput = 'RANDOMHTML
    <img src="http://example.com/image/SOMERANDOMIMG.jpg" alt="SOMERANDOMALTTEXT">
    <img src="http://example.com/image/SOMERANDOMIMG.jpg" alt="SOMERANDOMALTTEXT">
    <img src="http://example.com/image/SOMERANDOMIMG.jpg" alt="SOMERANDOMALTTEXT">
    RANDOMHTML' ;
```

I want to delete all the images before the last one, there might be images in the RANDOMHTML
 as well, I want to ignore those. These images are the same image over and over, but in different sizes, 
 so the images have different names.... 140x80.jpg, 280x160.jpg etc. And another note, the extension isnt always jpg
 some are png, gif etc as well.

All I want is the last image tag since it is usually the smallest. (CSS overrides anyway)

```
    $output = 'RANDOMHTML
    <img src="http://example.com/image/SOMERANDOMIMG.jpg" alt="SOMERANDOMALTTEXT">
    RANDOMHTML' ;
```

I'm thinking some sort of str_replace with count function or something.

Comment: Is the "back to back" images surrounded by a div or such?

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using using explode :

```
$string = 'RANDOMHTML
<img src="http://example.com/image/SOMERANDOMIMG.jpg" alt="SOMERANDOMALTTEXT">
<img src="http://example.com/image/SOMERANDOMIMG.jpg" alt="SOMERANDOMALTTEXT">
<img src="http://example.com/image/SOMERANDOMIMG.jpg" alt="SOMERANDOMALTTEXT">
RANDOMHTML' ;


$ex_string = explode('<img', $string);
```

now here you will get all the explode strings.. now you just need first and last string to make the query as you wanted..

```
echo $ex_string[0].'<img '.$ex_string[3]; // we are adding img tag because it must have been removed due to explode
//here $ex_string[0] is all the html that came before the first image is encountered
//and $ex_string[3] would be the last image data and all the data HTML appending it

 ?>
```

and this will give you the desired string.

Comment: `there might be images in the RANDOMHTML as well`

Comment: would those image have the same 'prefix' src as those of the required one ?

Comment: like : src='http://example.com/image/img1.jpg' and src="http://example.com/image/img2.jpg" etc.. ?

Comment: Actually that would solve half of what I am looking for... duh moment... so all I would need to do is figure out a way to find in the array lines that are just the img tag by itself...

Comment: $ex_string[0] = "<p>some random stuff...</p>foobar ..." ;
$ex_string[1] = "<img src='animageiwanttokeep.jpg' alt=foo'><p>more randomhtml</p>' ;
$ex_string[2] = "<img src='firstimageidontwant.jpg' alt='foo'>" ;
$ex_string[3] = "<img src='imgiwant.png' alt=''><br>morehtml";

Only the images html code that stand by themselves I want to delete from the array since any others that I want will have more html connected to it following the closing of the img tag... 

giving you this one.